# How can i uninstall oracle-java7-installer

Tags: java, bash

I'm new to java, and I tried to uninstall java 7 using this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer
```

Then tested it by:

```
sudo dpkg --list |grep -i jdk
```

And got:

```
bash /usr/bin/java no such file or directory
```

Is there anything wrong?  If I install another version of java, will this error disappear ?

Comment: Yeah, just install java again. [This is a simple script](https://github.com/neurobin/OracleJDKInstaller) which you can use to install oracle java from a downloaded source (tar.gz)

Comment: thanks i tried it and worked well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any package with this name. In debian-like systems, the name of the package is openjdk-6-jre (version 6, obviously)´

Try to find the correct name with:

```
apt-cache search jdk
```

Anyway if the comand:

```
which java
```

don't return any path, probably you don't have installed java.
The oracle java is not be in the official repositories and you must donwload it directly from website and not require installation, only need copy the binaries.